# how to manage polish(poland) strings with stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, polish, polish-notation

I am facing issue with polish characters inside mysql stored procedure.

String is following :

> Premium American Twill -rozmiar dziecięcy -z naklejką SNAP BACK PRO

Getting following Error :

> Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x99cy -...' for column 'dirty_string' at row 1

Following is my database and table schema

```
**Variable_name**                **Value**

character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database          latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server            latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: I would recommend writing code in English.

Comment: @Danieboy this is polish string in which I faced issue "Premium American Twill -rozmiar dziecięcy -z naklejką SNAP BACK PRO"